# remove You and ... others like this. from like plugin

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am playing with facebook like plugin and it works good here is my code:

```
<script>
(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id))
        return;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=746140538758786&version=v2.0";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

but there is a text : You and 794,828 others like this.  besides that which I want to remove that. I am wondering if there is any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you play with the options available in [Like Buttton - Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button)
the `button` layout removes everything, keeping only the button
if you're using `HTML5` you can add `data-layout="button"` to `.fb-like` `div`

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
```

or `iframe` version pass the parameter `layout=button`